# Using forEach() on an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I know how to get all the information on the web page another way, but I am trying to get it on the web page with the forEach() method to learn something new. This is my first time using the forEach() method can someone please tell what I am doing wrong? Everything but the values get printed onto the web page.

```js
let students = [
     { name: "Milla Jovovich", track: "Fullstack JavaScript", achievements: 5, points: 50 }
    ,{ name: "Bjon Aarseth", track: "iOS Development", achievements: 7, points: 70 }
    ,{ name: "Varg Oystein", track: "Front End Development", achievements: 12, points: 120 }
    ,{ name: "Wilhelm Striepe", track: "Software Engineering", achievements: 9, points: 90 }
    ,{ name: "Anders Hansen", track: "Data Science", achievements: 22, points: 220 }
] ;

let message = "";
let student;
let search;

function print(message) {
  let outputDiv = document.getElementById("output") ;
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message ;
}

students.forEach(function(myElement) {
  for(let key in myElement) {
          myElement += "<h2>Student: " + myElement[key] + "</h2>" ;
          myElement += "<p>Track: " + myElement[key] + "</p>" ;
          myElement += "<p>Achievements: " + myElement[key] + "</p>" ;
          myElement += "<p>Points: " + myElement[key] + "</p>" ;
  }
  
  print(myElement) ;
}) ;
```

```html
<div id="output">
```

Comment: You don't have any `HTML` element named `outputDiv` in your code mate

Comment: `myElement` refers to each student object. Why are you doing `myElement +=` inside `for...in` loop? Perhaps you meant to do `message+= ` and `print(message)`

Comment: I just added my HTML and CSS. I don't have an element named that. That's just what I named the variable. I do have an output ID in my HTML, though.

Comment: @adiga No, I wrote myElement there on purpose. It shouldn't be there, though. Message should be there. I didn't want to use the message variable to avoid scope confusion later. I'll just right a comment next to the declaration to remember that it is changed inside a function.

Comment: Also, it's better if you have different names for the global `message` variable and the `message` parameter of `print`

Comment: @adiga Ok, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for telling me this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Your inner for-loop is redundant as it adds the same value to every information block. Instead, you can remove it and access only the required keys for each of your objects (using dot-notation).
2. You are trying to concatenate a string with your object when you do `myElement += "string"` as `myElement` represents a given object in your array. Instead, you can use your empty string (`message`) and add to that at each iteration of your loop.

   Once you have done that, your `message` variable will contain the mark-up you need to print once your `.forEach` loop is complete, and so you can move the `print()` line to be outside your for loop.

See example below:

```js
let students = [{
    name: "Milla Jovovich",
    track: "Fullstack JavaScript",
    achievements: 5,
    points: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Bjon Aarseth",
    track: "iOS Development",
    achievements: 7,
    points: 70
  },
  {
    name: "Varg Oystein",
    track: "Front End Development",
    achievements: 12,
    points: 120
  },
  {
    name: "Wilhelm Striepe",
    track: "Software Engineering",
    achievements: 9,
    points: 90
  },
  {
    name: "Anders Hansen",
    track: "Data Science",
    achievements: 22,
    points: 220
  }
];

let message = "";

function print(message) {
  let outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML += message;
}

students.forEach(function(myElement) {
    message += "<h2>Student: " + myElement.name + "</h2>";
    message += "<p>Track: " + myElement.track + "</p>";
    message += "<p>Achievements: " + myElement.achievements + "</p>";
    message += "<p>Points: " + myElement.points + "</p>";
});

print(message);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Nick!

Comment: @HeavensGate666 no worries!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over your element with `for...in`. The `forEach` is enough.

```js
let students = [{
    name: "Milla Jovovich",
    track: "Fullstack JavaScript",
    achievements: 5,
    points: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Bjon Aarseth",
    track: "iOS Development",
    achievements: 7,
    points: 70
  },
  {
    name: "Varg Oystein",
    track: "Front End Development",
    achievements: 12,
    points: 120
  },
  {
    name: "Wilhelm Striepe",
    track: "Software Engineering",
    achievements: 9,
    points: 90
  },
  {
    name: "Anders Hansen",
    track: "Data Science",
    achievements: 22,
    points: 220
  }
];

let message = "";
let student;
let search;

function print(message) {
  let outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

message = ""; //declare your "message" here, the content of output

students.forEach(function(myElement) {
  message += "<h2>Student: " + myElement.name + "</h2>";
  message += "<p>Track: " + myElement.track + "</p>";
  message += "<p>Achievements: " + myElement.achivements + "</p>";
  message += "<p>Points: " + myElement.points + "</p>";
});

print(message); // print "message" when all students have been added to the variable
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```